# Python. Using CSV to read a file. Syntax Error

Tags: python, csv

The following script shows syntax error at line "with open..."

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput;
import  csv;

def read_csv_file ( file_name ):

    with open('file.csv', 'r') as my_csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file)
            for row in reader:
                print ( row )

read_csv_file();
```

Comment: The import statement should either be indented, or moved out of the function.  Indentation is syntactically significant in python.  In general import statements should not be in functions, they should be at the top of your file.

Comment: Your example has an indentation error at `import csv` before making it to the syntax error. Please update to a runnable example that shows the error... including putting `<= SYNTAX ERROR` into a comment. We want to run exactly what you run.

Comment: Removed "import csv" statement. Still syntax error.

Comment: After removing the import statement there was no syntax error for me. What version of python are you using? (`import sys;print sys.version`). If you have something very old, it may not support `with` clauses.

Comment: @tdelaney : Version 3.5.0

Comment: hopefully you didn't just delete the import statement. hopefully you placed it above the function definition, not indented.

Comment: With python 3.x, I would expect a syntax error at the `print row` line. Print is now a function `print(row)`. Is that where the problem is?

Comment: obviously you need to import csv.

Comment: You don't need semicolons in Python. Remove them forthwith!

Comment: @MattDMo. Removed all semi-colons. Still error

Comment: @tdelaney : Changed it to print(row). Still error.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace... it may have hints.

Comment: @tdelaney : $  ./csv.py
  File "./csv.py", line 8
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as my_csv_file:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your shebang `#!/usr/bin/python`.... that's python 2. Its only relevant if you run the program directly from the command line.

Comment: Can you post the traceback as a code block in the exception itself? What you show us is exactly what we'd expect for python 2.4. Did you add `import sys;print(sys.version)` to verify? As another aside, don't name your module "csv.py" because `import csv` will re-import your file instead of the system csv mode.

Comment: @tdelaney already mentioned that in my answer :)

Comment: @MattDMo so you did! I can't keep up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as my_csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print ( row )
```

has incorrect indentation. It should be:

```
with open('file.csv') as my_csv_file: # the 'r' mode is implicit
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file)
    for row in reader: # this line shouldn't have been indented
        print(row)
```

Additionally, the `#!/usr/bin/python` will run the script with Python 2, not Python 3. Your system may have a very old version of Python 2 (2.4 or previous) that doesn't recognize the [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) context manager. If you *must* have a shebang, make it `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5` or something similar. Or, if you're not planning on setting the script as executable and running it as `./scriptname.py` or whatever, just get rid of it entirely.

One more thing - don't name your file `csv.py`, as that will conflict with the `csv` module. Avoid naming files after any modules on your system. `csv_test.py` would be a better alternative, for example.

Comment: there were two errors : the shebang was incorrectly pointing to old version of Python (2.x). But more interesting is that the name of the file itself was causing the error. Once I renamed the file from csv.py to "csv_test.py", it worked as expected. complete  $ ./csv.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./csv.py", line 3, in <module>import      csv
  File "csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file)
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'
$ mv csv.py ./csv_test.py
$ ./csv_test.py
['first_name \tlast_name']